# Store information in a PNG file without distorting the image?

Tags: java, png

I want to write informations (former: int/String) into a PNG-file without making the changes visible to the human eye.

In order to achieve this i extract the file in the form of a Byte array:

```
byte[] imageAsBytes = fileInputStream.readAllBytes();
```

In the next step i jump the header (8 Bytes, already tried up to 300Bytes). I already have my information processed and can extract it bitwise.

I replace the last Bit from the picture`s Bytes with the Bitwise extracted information.

This works well with the .bmp file format but applying this technique to PNG-files distorts the image.

My guess is that the PNG-file contains additional information after the header.

So is there any information stored after the header and if so what marks this "information-part" as one?

Comment: A quick google search can get you the PNG file format (wiki has it, for one).

Comment: @Phil M Oh yeah the english wiki got it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to read and decode a .png file we can use `BufferedImage` as it follows:

```
File imageFile = new File("myimage.png");
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
```

No we can manipulate its pixels using `getRGB` and `setRGB` methods:

```
int pixel = image.getRGB(x, y);
// do some byte manipulation on the pixel
// ....
image.setRGB(x, y, pixel);
```

After this the `BufferedImage` should be piped to an output stream to be able to save the new image.

Comment: Sounds interseting. I will try it as soon as i get my school project done!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way will be not look at file bytes, but open it with some png decoder then change pixels at image itslef then save it again using png. When You will play with file bytes itself for sure You will broke the format of png, You didnt in bmp becasue bmp its jsut pixel by pixel saved drectly to file wihout any packaging or encoding